# How to Effectively Manage Asynchronous Tasks in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I am attempting to use the TPL in a windows service for efficient asynchronous processing. The service runs in an infinite loop, until the service is cancelled.

Here is the code that I'm using for the main service methods:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
private readonly List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Worker(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }, cancellationTokenSource.Token));
}

private async void Worker(CancellationToken token)
{
    bool keepGoing = true;

    while (keepGoing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            //Parallel.ForEach(processors, processor =>
            //{
            await processor.Process();
            //});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
            {
                keepGoing = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //write log here
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Delay(configurationSettings.OperationSettings.ServiceOperationDelay, token).ContinueWith(tsk => { });
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    using var mres = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    using (cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => mres.Set()))
    {
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), (t) => mres.Set());
        mres.Wait();
    }
}
```

The call to the processor basically does the following:

```
var records = await interfaceService.Get()

foreach record retrieved
       await interfaceService.Patch()
```

The service utilizes an HttpClient instance to make requests.

```
        **Get:**
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                                         "");

        using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //return results
        }
        else
        {
            throw Exception("Foo bar")
        }

        **Patch**
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, "")
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

The issue that I am encountering is that if the endpoint becomes unavailable, the service just doesn't effectively catch any exception or responses returned and for a lack of better terminology, falls in a hole. I believe my issue is with the way that the tasks are being managed.

What I want to ultimately be able to do is have the service with each iteration of the loop

1. Fire off specific tasks asynchronously, which perform the get/patch operation, at once
2. Wait until all are completed.
3. Log results of each to a file
4. Go to sleep
5. Start at step #1

In addition, when the service stops, I want to gracefully stop processing of each task.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to add any logging to the service to figure out where exactly it is hanging?

Comment: What do you expect happen by registering for cancellation on canceled token

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?